# mgwt vs. GWT Mobile - Platform compatibilities

Tags: windows-phone-7, gwt, cordova, mobile, mgwt

I am trying to decide which framework to use to my new project: mgwt or GWT Mobile (and PhoneGap). I already have an iOS and a Android Version of my App, so I am more interested in supporting platforms like Blackberry, Windows Phone, Symbian, WebOS and maybe Bada.

So here my question: are mgwt and GWT Mobile compatible with those platforms? Which one should I use in order to support as many platforms as possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now both frameworks do not support windows phone. GWT Mobile does not seem to support blackberry, mgwt does. Considering other webkit based browsers (bada symbian) you should be thinking about writing a low feature version of your app. (mgwt is talking about supporting such a thing).

That said mgwt is under heavy development and we will likely see many things happening in the framework:
mgwt is build by Daniel Kurka who is part of the GWT steering committee that develops GWT together with Google.

Here is an article from the GWT blog about mobile support with mgwt: http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.de/2012/07/gwt-support-for-mobile-app-development.html